# how to send data to Codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter

i want to send Values to the controller.how can i do it?

```
$("#Select").click(
    function()
    {
        var Values = [];    
        $("#option :selected").each(
                function()
                {
                Values.push($(this).val()); 
                 });

         alert(Values);

        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: By submitting a `<form>` or through `ajax`.

Comment: how can i do it with ajax?i am a beginner in ajax

Comment: See answer by @raheel posted below.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-8-ajax/) video tutorial. This might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will have to use ajax request

```
$("#Select").click(
    function()
    {
        var Values = [];    
        $("#option :selected").each(
        function()
        {
            Values.push($(this).val()); 
        });

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '<?php echo site_url("controllername/mymethod")?>',
            data : 'myarray='+Values,
            success : function(){
                // do whatever you want 
            } 
        });
        return false;
    }
);
```

In Controller accept values like this

```
function mymethod(){
    $array  =   $this->input->post('myarray');
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: is there a way that each value i select get stored into an array without using multiple select